# Explain Push and Pop Loop

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, callstack, masm32

These days, I'm used assembly language for self-study and been using MASM32.However, I don't understand about some code lines. I need a better explanation.

```
mov eax,20
loop1: 
push eax 
invoke StdOut, addr HelloWorld 
pop eax 
dec eax 
jnz loop1
```

Without the push and pop, it will print out 'Hello World' infinite !

My question:

> Why do we have to push and pop eax register?
>
> Does StdOut internally changes the value of that register?

Answer (score 1):

Because the call to the `STDOUT` routine changes the `EAX` register (and maybe that's not the only one...)

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You're exactly right. Before you call a subroutine that may change one or more registers, standard practice is to push them onto the stack, where they'll be preserved, before calling the subroutine. After the subroutine returns, you pop the values off of the stack in the reverse order and store them back in the original registers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice when you call a subroutine that **does not assure to preserve the registers you are interested in**; so, you **save them on stack** (push) and take them back (pop) after the call.

In some cases, it could be that functions are guarateed to preserve some registers, but "scratch" others. When you know that such conventions exist, you can choose a register instead of another in order to avoid the `push/pop` pattern. (The deal is done simply in the callee by pushing the registers that must be preserved, and popping them just before the return to the caller).

E.g.  when you call a function of the C standard library ("cdecl" [calling-convention](/questions/tagged/calling-convention) in force) on a x86 machine, you need to save "only" `eax`, `ecx` and `edx`, if you need to keep their values.